# Is it a good idea to load everything in to one variable in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Take the following for example:

```
// Load Required Modules
var Express  = require('express'),           // Express Framework
    Session  = require('express-session');   // Express Sessions
    App      = Express(),                    // Express Application
    HTTP     = require('http').Server(App),  // HTTP Server
    Parser   = require('body-parser'),       // Request Body Parser
    Moment   = require('moment');            // Date Manipulation And Formatting


var Application = {};

Application.ExpressFramework = Express;
Application.Express = App;
Application.Parser = Parser;
Application.Moment = Moment;

// Load Internal Modules
Application.Services = require('./modules/services')(Application);
Application.Models = require('./models')(Application);
etc
etc


Application.Services.Start();
```

As you can see, everything is being loaded in to one variable which is then passed around all the modules so they can access everything.

Is this a bad practice and if so, why? (Not looking for personal opinions - as per StackOverflow rules, just wondering if this would cause negative performance).

Comment: You just group coupled things together as anywhere else in your software.

Comment: I can't think of a case where you would need to do this.  It smells of bad design to me, but I suppose there might be a use case.  Can you elaborate on why you're doing this?

Comment: The only reason I thought to do this was because I didn't want to hassle of passing each item in to each module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if you want to pass a group of variables around to a bunch of different modules, then it is a natural way to group them into an object so you can pass just that single object rather than a long list of individual variables.  It is also much more extensible.

The node.js module pattern also supports the `exports` mechanism as one way of doing just this, but it is more of a "pull" model where another model does a `require` on you and fetches your exports.

The code you show is more of a "push" model where you load another module and then pass your variables to it which is another reasonable way to do things and works out better logically sometimes.

But ... some of the things you are sharing and the way you are sharing them does not seem ideal to me.

---

In the particular example you show, it is a little odd to be sharing some of the things you are sharing.  For example, there's no need to share the `Moment` or `Parser` variable.  If another module needs one of those modules, it should just do it's own `require('moment');` and get the module that way.

That makes your other module more stand-alone (it requires the things that it needs).  The `require` subsystem caches modules so it is not physically reloading the module when you do a 2nd `require()` on the same module.

There are occasionally reasons to share the `App` or `HTTP` variables from your code because those are instances of something that you don't want multiple instances of, not modules.  I would probably not put these in a single large object, but rather I'd pass them only to the modules that actually need them.  When you put lots of things in an object and pass the whole object to several other modules (each of which only use some of the things in the object), it makes it very difficult to tell what really depends upon what.  If, on the other hand, you pass another module only what it needs, then the code is very clear about what is really being used by the other module.

Comment: Great answer, explained very well.